# works with chrome but not with firefox, Eventlistener, appendChild and style.backgroundColor

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, addeventlistener

I played around with js and tried to make the user choose a background color.
My script first displays all colors from an array as div plus a button, then you can click a button to apply this color as background color.
It works in Chrome for me but not in Firefox. Am I making a huge mistake?

```
<html>
<head><meta charset=utf-8></head>
<body onload="always()" id="body">
</body>
<script>
all_colors = ["#FFFF00","#FF00FF","#00B3FF",]

function always(){  
    for  (i=0; i< all_colors.length; i++){  
        var e = document.createElement("div"); 
        e.id="box"+(i);
        e.style.backgroundColor = all_colors[i];
        document.getElementById("body").appendChild(e);
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.id = (i);
        var t = document.createTextNode(i);
        btn.appendChild(t);         
        e.appendChild(btn);         
    }
}  
document.addEventListener("click",function(){myfunc()})

function myfunc(){
    var el=document.activeElement;
    var i=el.id;
    choose_bg(i);
}

function choose_bg(i){
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = all_colors[i]
}

</script>
</html>
```

After some testing the problem maybe is the "actve Element" which works properly in Chrome but not in FF or Safari. By the way I am using a Mac, on my Android FF it works! maybe someone knows a solution...

Comment: i tested your code and it is working fine with me in firefox.i cant really say what is wrong with your code,maybe your firefox version is outdated??

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in FF?

Comment: I'm using FF 38.0.5, no errors are displayed anywhere.

Comment: I set an alert(el) into myfunc(). In chrome it response the [html button element], but in Firefox it always says [html body element], so it doesn't get the pushed button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you could try to use the following code to avoid the call to "activeElement" if you suspect there is a bug on it in your FF version:

```
<html>
<head><meta charset=utf-8></head>
<body onload="always()" id="body">
</body>
<script>
all_colors = ["#FFFF00","#FF00FF","#00B3FF",]

function always(){  
    for  (i=0; i< all_colors.length; i++){  
        var e = document.createElement("div"); 
        e.id="box"+(i);
        e.style.backgroundColor = all_colors[i];
        document.getElementById("body").appendChild(e);
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.id = (i);

        btn.addEventListener("click", myfunc);

        var t = document.createTextNode(i);
        btn.appendChild(t);
        e.appendChild(btn);
    }
}  

function myfunc(event){
    var eventSource = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var i = eventSource.id;
    choose_bg(i);
}

function choose_bg(i){
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = all_colors[i]
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You are awesome! That works..
I did a more complex workaround by replacing the buttons with text-inputs which are looking like buttons for all browsers except chrome :)